# best way to get 2 values from html in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup and I want to scrape 2 attribute values in python.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="123456789">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="987654321">
```

I want to get both the values. This is the code that I'm using right now

```
number = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
final = number.find('input')['name']
soup.find('input')['value']
print(final [2])
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  How to find these elements?  Or how to extract the values after they are found?

Comment: i want to find them and extract both of them. right now I can only find the 1st one.

Comment: Update the question to show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: `.find(...)` returns the first match. You'd want `.find_all(...)` and a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.find()` which gives you only first tag. You should be using [`.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get all `input` tags then grab values out of them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="123456789">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="987654321">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
values = [each.attrs['value'] for each in soup.find_all('input')]
# -> ['123456789', '987654321']
```